# Listening for DOMContentLoaded event from child frame

Tags: javascript, events, iframe, frame, domcontentloaded

I want to know when a navigation event occurs in a child frame, when the child frame's new document content has been loaded, but not wait for all the images and other resources to be loaded.  (It is a legacy `frameset` document, though seems, in all major browsers, to generally behave as if it's a document containing `iframe`s.)

Listening for the `window.load` event works, but the event is not triggered until all images etc. are loaded.  Listening for the `document.DOMContentLoaded` does not.  I have tried waiting for the first `load` event before setting the `DOMContentLoaded` event handler, but to no avail.

Is the problem that the document has been changed, so the original document that the event was attached to no longer exists?  If so, is there a `window` event I can use that would trigger at the same time as `DOMContentLoaded`?  Or do I need to use `postMessage` to achieve what I'm trying to do?

I'm looking for a quick answer from someone who knows.  If it's possible to listen for `DOMContentLoaded` in this situation, I'd rather do that, than implement a `postMessage` solution unnecessarily.

The documents are same origin, so CORS is not an issue.

Comment: Weirdly, in Firefox, if I set a handler for `message`, the `DOMContentLoaded` handler set in `load` does actually get called.  Seems not in Chrome but the console log appears to be buggy that browser and sometimes doesn't show anything.  (I am logging the events in the callback so I know which event type is triggered.)

Comment: In Chrome, sometimes the child frame doesn't exist when setting listeners, despite use of `setTimeout(0)`, so a retry is sometimes necessary.  That explains the odd behaviour referred to in my previous comment.